# How to use a migration tool in Django 1.6 and sqlite 2.8?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm new to Django and databases in general. I made a new app and than added a class to its model. After that I added another thing to my class, and I ran this command "python3.2 manage.py sql todo". and I got this

```
CREATE TABLE "todo_item" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"description" text NOT NULL,
"dueDate" date NOT NULL,
"status" varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
COMMIT;
```

I thought that will do it, but I still get this error:

```
Exception Value: no such column: todo_item.status
```

status is the new thing that I want to add to my item class.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py syncdb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`manage.py sql todo` just prints the SQL to create the table.  This SQL is not executed against the db.

To create the table you should run `manage.py syncdb`.

But I suggest you to use the [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) app which provides the real migrations.

**UPDATE**: To add the new column to the existing empty table run the following command:

```
echo "ALTER TABLE todo_item ADD COLUMN status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;" | python manage.py dbshell
```

If the table is not empty and you can't delete the data from it then you have to set the default value for that column:

```
echo "ALTER TABLE todo_item ADD COLUMN status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new';" | python manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Also, you can move to django 1.7 which have built in migration system.

Comment: Of course. If the OP can choose the version then the switching to 1.7 is a right move.

Comment: @catavaran thanks for the comment, sadly I have to use 1.6 because it is for a school project.

Comment: If the table already exists then the `syncdb` does nothing. This command doesn't alter the tables. See the updated answer.